# Select a candidate based on count and percentage in PHP

Tags: php, percentage

I have a list of ads, I would like to rotate them based on the rotation (which represents a percentage) and the number of times it has been viewed. There can be any number of ads, and they are listed within a multidimensional array. Each line is one ad. Each time it is viewed, viewed increases +1.

```
$aAd[] = array('viewed' => 2003, 'rotation' => 70); // 70%
$aAd[] = array('viewed' => 122, 'rotation' => 30); // 30%
```

I am trying to work out how to select the next ad to display based on the rotation and the number of times it has been viewed. Is anyone able to help with the formula to do this?

The algorithm needs to select the next one to display, it should choose it based on the number of times it has been viewed and the percentage it should be viewed (the rotation). The order of the ads are not presently in any specific order. The rotation represents the desired percentage in which the client would like the ads displayed. It is fine if an ad is picked twice in a row, as long as the rotation equals out to 70/30 in this example. Keep in mind, there can be any number of ads and they can have different rotations assigned as well.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Firstly $aAds is 2 times, are they 2 seperate ads? and i think you should use object instead of array also you talk about percentage so where is it?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question...

Comment: You want to rotate a ad does it mean increase rotation value(which is also percentage) by 1.

Comment: Each time it is viewed, viewed increases +1

Comment: Which one is the one that is currently viewed? The first one in the array? What does a "rotation" do? Pick one from the array and shift it in the first position? Or is the order in the array never changed? Is it possible for one to be picked twice in a row?

Comment: The algorithm needs to select the next one to display, it should choose it based on the number of times it has been viewed and the percentage it should be viewed (the rotation). The order of the ads are not presently in any specific order. The rotation represents the desired percentage in which the client would like the ads displayed. Yes, it's fine if an ad is picked twice in a row, as long as the rotation is 70/30. Keep in mind, there can be any number of ads and they can have different rotations assigned as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function getNextAdIndex($aAd) {
    $scores = array_map(function ($ad) { return $ad["viewed"] / $ad["rotation"]; }, $aAd);
    return array_search(min($scores), $scores);
}
```

It returns the index in `$aAd` that is the one that has the least views in comparison with what it ideally should have (based on its rotation percentage).

#### Example use

```
$aAd[] = array('viewed' => 0, 'rotation' => 70); // 70%
$aAd[] = array('viewed' => 0, 'rotation' => 30); // 30%

// Provide the next 100 views:    
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $j = getNextAdIndex($aAd);
    echo "showing add $j\n"; // Do whatever is needed to "display" an ad here
    $aAd[$j]["viewed"]++; // Increase its number of views
}
```